# No local JVM's were detected, not even the jvm running this instance of java mission control

Tags: java, jvm

I'm new at Java, and I've just recently installed it and set the environmental variables.

But when I try to compile something, it says:

> ```
> javac: file not found: BoleanTest.java
> Usage: javac <options> <source files>
> use -help for a list of possible options
> ```

And when I open JVM it says:

> No local JVM's were detected, not even the jvm running this instance of java mission control.

Help please, thank you.

([A photo of the error as shown on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxCnQ.jpg))

Comment: Do you have the JDK properly installed and classpathed?

Comment: What does "open JVM" mean?

Comment: Secondly you should really use a proper IDE like NetBeans or Intellij IDEA ( no, notepad++ isnt one), and you should make yourself familar with your operating system, especially its console.

Comment: You're obviously in the wrong directory.

Comment: also BooleanTest is spelled different in the source code as the file name or you are just running is with the wrong spelling

Comment: The message "No local JVM's were detected, not even the jvm running this instance of java mission control." is displayed in the profiling tool Java Mission Control which you start with the command %JDK%\bin\jmc . It seems like that was not what you intended, and is unrelated to your actual problem of running javac on the commandline. You should probably have used another question title.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are in the same location as your .java file in your terminal. It seems that you are in the wrong directory.

Or

you can execute javac command from a different location as your java file like this: javac C:\Program Files\SomeDirectory\Test.java

Answer (score 1):

In command prompt the currently active folder is `C:\Program Files\Notepad++` 
However your file is created on your Desktop (`C:\Users\Alban Selmanaj\Desktop\BoleanTest.java`).

As a starting point try the following command before attempting to run javac:

```
 cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

Please confirm if it helps or not.

Comment: Originally the content above was suggested as edit to @Eugene's answer, but it got rejected, hence posting it as a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal you are in `C:\Program Files...` and your file is created at `C:\Users\...`. You are *obviously* missing your paths here

Comment: When i wrote such answers back when i was one of those 1000rep users, people downvoted me because *thats not an answer*... Im surprised that no one does so here.

Comment: @JonasW. :) true. you are free to downvote if u want to btw.

Comment: Well @Eugene care to rework your answer to make it more obvious for the user what he need to do?

Comment: can you explain it to me please because i have to do a project at school and i can't find to fix this problem

Comment: @AlbanSelmanaj you need to `cd C:\Users\Alban...` - go to the path where your file is present